# How to copy a file into folder and all its subdirectories

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I found some topics on superuser which helped me, but I'm still stuck at some place.

I found out that to copy file through command-promt I can use: `Copy index.html forms`.
But this command copies index.html only to forms folder, but not to its subdirectories.

I want index.html file to be copied to forms folder and all other folders which are in the forms folder (subdirectories).

Thanks

Comment: You asked how to copy a file with it's subdirectories (like index.html and the linked subdirectory index_files) or a directory with it's subdirectories ?

Comment: A file does not have any subdirectories to copy from.  You can only specify one destination to copy to.  Your request therefore makes no sense.

Comment: @sawdust You can copy to multiple subdirectories using the method in my answer.

Comment: @paradroid --  Glad to see that you understood what the OP was asking.  My comment was also directed at the prior comment and answer that didn't seem to understand the question at all.  And I should have clarified that I was only thinking of a (basic) copy command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %G in (`dir path\to\forms /b /s /a:d`) do copy path\to\index.html "%~G"
```

Answer (score 1):

from MS help pages:

[Xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true)

Copies files and directories, including subdirectories.

In the examples section you have got this:

> To copy all the files and subdirectories (including any empty
>   subdirectories) from drive A to drive B, type:
>
> xcopy a: b: /s /e